# Finding permutation of jobs such that each job finishes before deadline

Tags: algorithms

Consider a set of jobs, each having its deadlines and process time. How to find a permutation of them such that if they are executed in that sequence, they all finish before their deadline 
 or figure out that no such permutation exists.

**My Thoughts:** 
There could be some greedy strategy, but I am not sure how to arrive at that.

Answer (score 2):

The greedy strategy you are looking for is Earliest-Deadline-First and it's optimal in minimizing maximum lateness.

Minimizing sum of latenesses is NP-complete.

Comment: So we won't be considering process time at all? Simply sort the jobs by deadlines in ascending order and process them in that order. Is that correct?

Comment: You can find more info in the text book Algorithm Design and the corresponding slides for [greedy algorithms](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/04GreedyAlgorithmsI.pdf) (pdf).